# Access ForeignKey models and fill in its fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Please help me how to access author models and fill in the user field

My models:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='کاربر',blank=True, null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/user_avatar/', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='عکس کاربر')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='توضیحات و رزمه')
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False, unique=True, verbose_name='عنوان')
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/article_cover/', null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='عکس مقاله')
    content = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False, verbose_name='متن مقاله')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='تاریخ')
    category = models.ManyToManyField('Category', blank=False, verbose_name='دسته بندی', related_name='article')
    author = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='انتشار دهنده',null=True)
```

Article Adding Class

```
class ArticleCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, FieldMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'registration/article_create.html'
    model = Article
    fields = ['title', 'cover', 'content', 'category', 'author', ]

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            form.save()
        else:
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.author.user = self.request.user
            obj.save()
         
        return super(ArticleCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

The result of these codes is this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DClN5.png)

Comment: if you don't save your foreign key how can you access foreign key's value?

Comment: I deleted the author field display if the user was not superuser and I want the author name to be filled in automatically

Comment: you can create an author object(user=request.user, avatar=None, description=None) and save with obj.author = author object

Comment: I wrote this :   obj.author = UserProfile(user=self.request.user, avatar=None, description=None) But this gave an error: save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'author'.

Comment: from django1.8 and above you can't set foreign key with an unsaved object, you need to save that UserProfile object first then set

Comment: Thank you I worked with this line of my project codeform.instance.author = UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)  What you said is trying to create data in the database